# Unable to set emulator Date via Espresso adb

Tags: android, adb

How to set Date on emulator for Espresso test ?
I am trying to use below code, but I am getting Permission denied error.

```
adb shell
```

1. Get current Date - OK

   ```
   $ date
   // returns  
   Sun Jan  9 18:28:27 CET 2022
   ```
2. Set Date to another - FAILED

   ```
   $ date -u 012610202016    
   // returns                                                                          
   date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted
   Tue Jan 26 10:20:00 UTC 2016
   ```

My emulator is Android 10.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are using an emulator, then you can do the following:

```
$ su
$ date -u 012610202016
```

This avoids the `Operation not permitted` error and will successfully set the date to `Tue Jan 26 10:20:00 UTC 2016`.